# Algorithm/C++ code for extracting patterns from text file

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, text-parsing

A file containing a large switch case is given as input. The cases are incremented from 0 to n. Each case has some specific elements (a, b, etc).

Output will consist of three things: a vector containing all the unique elements, a second vector containing the first position (case) where the element is used and lastly, a third vector containing the periodicity of the elements.

Input will be a text file like this:

```
//standard comment useful for parsing file
switch something
{

case 0:
    a;
    b;
    c;
    break;

case 1:
    break;

case 2:
    a;
    break;

case 3:
    d;
    break;

case 4:
    a;
    d;
    break;

}
```

Output:

Vector 1 will be {a, b, c, d}

Vector 2 will be {0, 0, 0, 3}

Vector 3 will be {2, 0, 0, 1} *Note: 0 is for non-cyclic elements, 2 is the 
    difference of the cases between two consecutive appearances of the element 
    (case 4 - case 2 = case 2 - case 0 = 2). This difference will repeat itself 
    so we only need to compare whichever two consecutive appearances.

Also, this algorithm should work for very large files numbering hundreds of thousands of lines of code.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822

Comment: No effort usually reaps no results.

Comment: There are several parts to this problem: reading the file, finding the cases, finding the elements, building the data structure, and computing the results. Which part(s) are you having trouble with? I would suggest that you try to break the problem down and do it step-by-step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that format of the text file is consistent and is exactly how it is described in the question, one way to do it would be by reading lines and parsing as you go. I am sure there is a better way of doing it, but without getting too involved, here is what I've got:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inputFile("cases.txt");

    std::vector<char> uniqueChars;
    std::vector<int> firstCase;
    std::vector<int> periodicity;

    std::string inputLine;
    while (std::getline(inputFile, inputLine, '\n'))
    {
        if (inputLine.compare(0, 5, "case ") == 0)
        {
            int caseN = std::stoi(inputLine.substr(5));
            while (std::getline(inputFile, inputLine, '\n') && inputLine != "    break;")
            {
                std::istringstream iss(inputLine);
                char c, semi;
                while (iss >> c >> semi)
                {
                    auto found = std::find(uniqueChars.begin(), uniqueChars.end(), c);
                    if (found == uniqueChars.end())
                    {
                        uniqueChars.push_back(c);
                        firstCase.push_back(caseN);
                        periodicity.push_back(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        size_t charPos = std::distance(uniqueChars.begin(), found);
                        if (periodicity[charPos] == 0)
                        {
                            periodicity[charPos] = std::abs(caseN - firstCase[charPos]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // print

    for (auto c : uniqueChars)
        std::cout << c << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (auto i : firstCase)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (auto p : periodicity)
        std::cout << p << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output for the sample file:

[image]